# Regex | explode | str_split to match number in a title

Tags: php, regex, string, split, explode

I'm giving an example so you can understand what I want to achieve.
I got this titles:

```
$t1 = "Disposizione n. 158 del 28.1.2012";
$t2 = "Disposizione n.66 del 15.1.2006";
$t3 = "Disposizione f_n_66 del 15.1.2001";
$t4 = "Disposizione numero 66 del 15.1.2018";
$t5 = "Disposizione nr. 66 del 15.1.2017";
$t6 = "Disposizione nr_66 del 15.1.2016";
$t7 = "Disposizione numero_66 del 15.1.2005";
```

Until now I had tried:

```
$output = explode(' ', $t1);

foreach ($output as $key => $value) {

if($value == 'n.' || $value == 'numero' || $value == 'n' || $value == 'nr' || $value == 'nr.') {
    $number= $output[($key+1)];
    break;
}
}

print_r($attoNumero);
```

But this is a limited solution because it does not work on all titles. How can I use `Regex`,`explode`,`str_split`, or anything else to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried any regex pattern yet?

Comment: No because I'm not good at it... that's why I'm asking for any solution that can be in PHP or Regex

Comment: Does it mean you just want to extract the first number? All these numbers are first numbers in each string.

Comment: There as some cases which is not the first number. But the required number will be always after some `n.` or `numero` or `nr_` ecc.

Comment: example: `Disposizione del 31.12.2007 n. 1272`

Comment: What's the expected output for each title?

Comment: the number after `n.` or `number` or `n_` ecc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```php
if (preg_match('~(?<![^\W_])n(?:r?[_.]|umero_?)\s*\K\d+~i', $text, $match)) {
    echo $match[0];
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DsvcHn/1/). *Details*:

- `(?<![^\W_])` - a word boundary with `_` position subtracted (right before, there must be start of string, or a non-alphanumeric char)
- `n` - `n` char
- `(?:r?[_.]|umero_?)` - either an optional `r` and then `_` or `.`, or `umero` and an optional `_` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace chars
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `\d+` -  one or more digits.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/jXOdP):

```php
$texts = ["Disposizione n. 158 del 28.1.2012", "Disposizione n.66 del 15.1.2006","Disposizione f_n_66 del 15.1.2001", "Disposizione numero 66 del 15.1.2018", "Disposizione nr. 66 del 15.1.2017", "Disposizione nr_66 del 15.1.2016", "Disposizione numero_66 del 15.1.2005"];
foreach ($texts as $text) {
    if (preg_match('~(?<![^\W_])n(?:r?[_.]|umero_?)\s*\K\d+~i', $text, $match)) {
        echo $match[0] . " found in '$text'" . PHP_EOL;
    } else echo "No match in $text!\n";
}
```

Output:

```
158 found in 'Disposizione n. 158 del 28.1.2012'
66 found in 'Disposizione n.66 del 15.1.2006'
66 found in 'Disposizione f_n_66 del 15.1.2001'
66 found in 'Disposizione numero 66 del 15.1.2018'
66 found in 'Disposizione nr. 66 del 15.1.2017'
66 found in 'Disposizione nr_66 del 15.1.2016'
66 found in 'Disposizione numero_66 del 15.1.2005'
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much! The answer will be accepted in 5 min. You are my savior for today. Happy coding!

Comment: Solved nicely with the lookbehind +1